# Postman - Aggregating or inculding tests

Tags: testing, collections, include, postman

I have a question about Postman, collections and aggregating them.

My project have a lot of Postman tests, how are already in many collections. For example, collection.A has 30 tests, collection.B has 45 tests, and so on.... To simpify the test execution, I would like to create a single collection that will call collections containing single tests. So it will be possible to run all tests in a single call.

For example:

```
Collection -calls--> Collection.A -has---> Test.A1, Test.A2...
                 I-> Collection.B -has---> Test.B1, Test.B2...
                 I-> Collection.C -has---> Test.C1, Test.C2...
```

Is it possible and how ?

So, I don't want to regroup all single tests in only one collection. Each collection must be executed separately...

Thanks in advance for yours tips.

Sony

----- Edit -----

I've created some folders and sub-folders to group my tests, and now the exported file is very tall - more than 130K lines and 5MB json-file. It contains 10 folders, each folder has 6-7 sub-folders and finally more than 2K single tests.

Is it a way to keep smaller files, maybe 1 file per sub-folder (as 1 collection) and to link them in higher-level collections until finally 1 single collection to regroup them all ?

Thanks

Comment: Create a single collection and make folders for each. And when you run that collection, all tests will be executed.

Comment: @Div: Thank you for your comment. I already use folders and it works as expected but the produced export file is now just enormous (about 130k lines)...